# Plotting a parallel line using tikz \draw plot

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm trying to draw a line (PC2), that passes through some arbitrary point (A) and is parallel to another line (PC1).

PC1 is defined by a gradient (PCslp) and a y intercept (PCint).  Obviously, as parallel lines, PC1 and PC2 have the same gradient.  The y intercept is differnet, and can be calculated using point (A) and the gradient: take the y value of (A) and subtract the x value of (A) multiplied by the gradient (PCslp).

The code I am using is as follows:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{calc}

\usetikzlibrary{calc,intersections}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
        PC/.style={red, thick},
        dot/.style={circle,fill=black,minimum size=4pt,inner sep=0pt,outer sep=-1pt}
      ]

% Define linear parameters 
\def\PCint{0.2}   %Y-intercept 
\def\PCslp{0.8}   %Slope 
\def\PC{\x,{\PCslp*\x+\PCint}}

\draw[PC, domain=0:5] 
  plot (\PC)
  node [right] {$PC_1$};

\draw [domain=0:5]
  let
    \p1=(61.28041pt, 26.23682pt),
    \n1={\y1-\PCslp*\x1} in

  % points the plot should pass through...
  node [dot,label=above:{$A$}] at (\x1,\y1) {}
  node [dot,label=above:{$B$}] at (0,\n1) {}

  % first try for a plot...
  plot ({\x,\PCslp*\x-\n1})
  node [right] {$PC_2$};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Unfortunately, the result I'm getting is not what I expected:

[image]

Can anybody point out what I'm doing wrong?

Cheers

nik

Comment: First,  plot ({\x,\PCslp*\x-\n1}) should be plot (\x,{\PCslp*\x+\n1}), but this doesn't work either.  If you leave out the +\n1 you get the right slope, and if you leave out the \PCslp*x you get the right intercept.

Comment: Aha!  \n1 is defined in screen units (-22.78769pt) and for some reason you cannot combine screen units and unscaled units in this calculation.

Comment: From the pgfmanual (page 132 of the current version): »An expression like `(2+3cm,0)` does not mean the same as `(2cm+3cm,0)`. Instead, if
`<x>` or `<y>` internally uses a mixture of dimensions and dimensionless values, then all dimensionless values
are “upgraded” to dimensions by interpreting them as pt. So, `2+3cm` is the same dimension as `2pt+3cm`.«

Answer (score 2):

A bit of a kludge, but it works:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{calc}

\usetikzlibrary{calc,intersections}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
        PC/.style={red, thick},
        dot/.style={circle,fill=black,minimum size=4pt,inner sep=0pt,outer sep=-1pt}
      ]

% Define linear parameters 
\def\PCint{0.2}   %Y-intercept 
\def\PCslp{0.8}   %Slope 
\def\PC{\x,{\PCslp*\x+\PCint}}

\draw[PC, domain=0:5] 
  plot (\PC)
  node [right] {$PC_1$};

\draw [domain=0:5]
  let
    \p1=(61.28041pt, 26.23682pt),
    \n1={\y1-\PCslp*\x1} in

  % points the plot should pass through...
  node [dot,label=above:{$A$}] at (\x1,\y1) {}
  node [dot,label=above:{$B$}] at (0,\n1) {}

  % first try for a plot...
  plot[yshift=\n1] (\x,\PCslp*\x)
  node [right,yshift=\n1] {$PC_2$};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: demo]